# MySQL create a sum number if row exists in table

Tags: mysql

I have a statement like so:

```
select * from category a 
inner join category b on a.row=b.relatedRow 
inner join category c on b.row=c.relatedRow where a.row=?
```

I would like to get the number of "levels" like so:

If **a** has rows, **level=1**, If **b** has rows, **level=2**, If **c** has rows, **level=3**.

How can I do this?

**Example**

```
row, relatedRow

1,null

2,1

3,2

4,3

5,2

6,5
```

So, 1 is not related to any row, 2 is related to 1, 3 is related to 2 and so on...

If row=1, level 1 exists since 1 exists

level 2 exists since 2 is related to 1

level 3 exists since 3 and 5 is related to 2

level 4 exists since 6 is related to 5 and 4 is related to 3

Therefore the this tree goes down 4 levels.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "has rows". Do you mean to say that if relatedRow is present in the joined table then you want to add a column `level=1,2,3`? Can you edit your post to show sample rows from `a,b,c` and the expected query output for the given sample input rows?

Comment: And what is the precedence? If b and c both have rows, is the level then 2(b) or 3(c)?

Comment: My table is like a tree. There are related rows of rows and those may also have related rows. I would like to find the number of levels the tree goes down. I know it has a limit of 3 levels. I need a number that gets generated telling me the number of levels this tree is according to the parameter. If A has rows, level 1, if B has rows, level 2, if C has rows, level 3... And I want to be able to use this number 1-3.

Comment: You refer to a "sum" in the question and I think that's throwing people off.

Comment: My mistake. I will fix this

Comment: I think *summary* was what you tried to say.

Answer (score 1):

try with something along the lines:

```
select 
    sum(case when not b.relatedRow  is null then 1 else 0 end) as level1_total 
    sum(case when not c.relatedRow  is null then 1 else 0 end) as level2_total
from category a 
left join category b on a.row=b.relatedRow 
left join category c on b.row=c.relatedRow where a.row=?
```

of course, you can modify the conditions in the `case` to suit your definition of *has rows*

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    max(
        case
            when c.relatedRow is not null then 3
            when b.relatedRow is not null then 2
            else 1
        end
    ) as "levels"
from
    A a
    left outer join B b on b.relatedRow = a.row
    left outer join C on c.relatedRow = b.row
```

Now seeing the edit to the question, I hope you see this pattern can be extended to a 4th level and beyond. If you add a `where` clause to do any filtering make sure that you only add conditions against `A` or you'll mess up the outer joins.